# Gibbs Sampler Consistency

Tags: probability, self-study, estimation, sampling, gibbs

Simple question that I haven't found easily online: why are the estimates obtained from a Gibbs sampler consistent (converge to the true probabilities)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under irreducibility conditions, the Gibbs sampler produces an ergodic and thus converging Markov chain. By virtue of the ergodic theorem, an empirical average based on such a Markov chain will converge to the associated expectation under the stationary distribution.